# Unable to create Pipeline using azure devops cli in Azure Devops Portal from Azure Repos

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-extensions

- I installed az cli and azure-devops extension.

```
>> az --version
azure-cli                         2.44.1

core                              2.44.1
telemetry                          1.0.8

Extensions:
azure-devops                      0.25.0

Dependencies:
msal                              1.20.0
azure-mgmt-resource             21.1.0b1

Python location 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\python.exe'
```

- set the default configuration for organization and project using

`az devops configure --defaults organization=<org> project=<project>`

- Run the following command

```
> az pipelines create --name 'MyCi'
Error: The following arguments are required: --repository
```

However according to [MicrosoftDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/pipelines?view=azure-cli-latest) the --repository parameter is Optional

- I am new to DevOps and don't know much about the devops-cliI.I try the full command.

```
> az pipelines create --name 'NameCI' --description 'pipeline for project' --repository AzureRepo
--branch main --repository-type tfsgit
Error: Page not found.  Operation returned a 404 status code.
```

- I can successfully create pipelines from browser
- I can delete pipelines from azure devops-cli but I cannot create pipelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/pipelines?view=azure-cli-latest#az-pipelines-create), I am trying to create an Azure Pipeline for a repository hosted in an Azure Repo in the same project.

```
az pipelines create --name 'ContosoBuild' --description 'Pipeline for contoso project' --repository SampleRepoName --branch master --repository-type tfsgit
```

I am receiving the same error message as yours.

By specifying the arguments "yml-path", the operation is successful.

[image]

Sample:

```
az pipelines create --name 'CreatedByCLI' --yml-path /azure-pipelines.yml --repository AzureCLIrepo --branch main --repository-type tfsgit
```

[image]

Output:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, Finally able to create a pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create pipelines from Azure DevOps CLI. There is no command az pipelines create thats why it returned Page not found.  Operation returned a 404 status code.

Comment: But according to [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/pipelines?view=azure-cli-latest) you can create piplines using Azure DevOps CLI.