# 404 error while creating pipeline using Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, devops

I am newly learning azure devops. I am trying to create an azure devops pipeline to build a sacala project.

In dev.azure.com, I have created an organization, it is called nitinxgupta9 and under this organization there is a project called TheBestAppEver. Under this project I am trying to create a pipeline to build the following GitHub scala project

https://github.com/nitin3000/ml

I am using the below azure cli windows prompt command

`az pipelines create --name "First-Java.CI" --org https://dev.azure.com/nitinxgupta9 --project TheBestAppEver --repository https://nitinxgupta9@dev.azure.com/nitinxgupta9/TheBestAppEver/_git/TheBestAppEver --branch master`

I am getting error

Page not found.  Operation returned a 404 status code.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the issue and I found I can create the pipeline after I added the  `--yml-path /azure-pipelines.yml` to the commamd.

```
az pipelines create --name "First-Java.test" --org https://dev.azure.com/orgname  --project projectname --repository reponame --branch main --yml-path /azure-pipelines.yml --repository-type tfsgit
```

[image]

You can refer this  [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75081137/unable-to-create-pipeline-using-azure-devops-cli-in-azure-devops-portal-from-azu) .